# Constructing a sentence with "in order"+infinitive

Tags: grammar

Is it a matter of writing style, or is one of these sentences more correct than the other?

- *In order to drive safely, you must anticipate the road conditions.*
- *You must anticipate the road conditions in order to drive safely.*

Secondary question: must the first example be punctuated? I am conscious of overusing commas.

Comment: Please excuse me if the question does not make sense; it's my first post on this stackexchange.

Comment: The two words "in order" in that construction are virtually always superfluous.

Comment: thanks, you're right. I wonder if there are examples where _"in order"_ is not superfluous? Or perhaps _"in order"_ is only used for emphasis.

Comment: "Superfluous" is a value judgement. _That_ is frequently deletable in relative clauses and complement clauses, for instance; but not always, and even when deletion is optional, it's not always advisable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both sentences are grammatically correct. You have a prepositional phrase which you have moved to the beginning of the sentence. That's perfectly fine. When moving prepositional phrases to the beginning of sentences, you can often choose to use a comma or not (as long as they don't contain years or place names that require commas). With longer phrases, it is advised to insert a comma to avoid confusion.